# Listen for beforeExit or SIGTERM to trigger cleanup in Node

Tags: node.js, heroku

I recently added something to a node.js app to listen for the `beforeExit` event and run a cleanup callback which closes MySQL connections before it exits.

However I have also seen several posts mentioning listening for the `SIGTERM` event for this process.

So wondering which is best to use? (specifically in a Heroku environment)

Comment: Have you tried listening for `SIGTERM`? Did it not work? What have you tried?

Comment: I had both set up, however wasn't sure if I needed both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a dyno needs to be stopped, heroku will send it a [SIGTERM](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm) indicating it that it needs to stop doing anything it's currently working on, and stop itself.

After 10 seconds, they will send a `SIGKILL`, which will force-kill the process (unless it killed itself first), with an [R12](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r12-exit-timeout) error.

Looking through [node's documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_beforeexit), it looks like beforeExit is executed when node is about to stop itself because it doesn't have anything to do anymore.
As mentioned in this documentation, it will **not** be executed when receiving a kill signal.

> 'beforeExit' is not emitted for conditions causing explicit termination, such as process.exit() or uncaught exceptions, and should not be used as an alternative to the 'exit' event unless the intention is to schedule more work.

So yes, you should listen to `SIGTERM` and stop anything your app is doing when that process is received.

See unix termination signals: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

Comment: Thanks for a great answer